# Is there a native way to parse a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

Say I want to access `a.b.c.d` and I'm not sure if `b` or `c` exist.
The 'naive' check would be:

```
if (a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d == 5) doSomething(a.b.c.d);
```

I thought this over and wrote this function that improves this:

```
Object.prototype.parse = function (keys, def) {
  return keys.split('.').reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    if (prev) {
      return prev[curr];
    }
  }, this) || def;

};
```

And you would use it like this:

```
var a = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 5
    }
  }
};

console.log(a.parse('b.c.d', 3)); // If b, c or d are undefined return 3
```

But I'm wondering if I'm missing a better, native way to achieve this instead of having to add this function to projects.

Thanks!

Comment: You could also just put an exception handler around it and just access `var x = a.b.c.d`.  It will either succeed, throw an exception or return `undefined` (if only `d` is missing).

Comment: There's a library called [`dotty`](https://github.com/deoxxa/dotty) for this sort of thing.

Comment: @jfriend00 The try..catch solution is significantly slower since it disabled interpreter optimizations

Comment: Where is that a requirement anywhere in your question?  You asked for a native way to do it.  I offered one.   And, then you go and accept an answer that requires a try/catch.  I'm confused.

Comment: Performance depends upon the browser.  try/catch solution (where you don't throw the exception) is much faster in Firefox, slower in other browsers.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry for confusing you. I selected that answer as the one since it offered insight on eval and suggested that I use dotty, which I haven't heard of or my own solution, which, in light of a lack of a native solution, is the best option.

Comment: @Ben - Using doty makes more sense.  It certainly wasn't clear that's why you selected the answer because the code in the answer doesn't do that at all.

Comment: There are dozens of answers here on SO related to this topic, both evaluating property strings of the form `a.b.c`, and doing the so-called "existential check" of `a && a.b && a.b.c`. Search for them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The only native way is [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), but I wouldn't recommend it as can be used to execute arbitrary code. This might be OK, but not if your "a.b.c.d" style strings come from untrusted users. I'd stick with your handcrafted solution or use [dotty](https://github.com/deoxxa/dotty).

```
var a = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 5
    }
  }
};
console.log(eval("a.b.c.d"));
```

eval() will throw the same error that the native equivalent would when b or c are not defined so you'll need to wrap with a try {} catch {} block.

Comment: I think he is trying to solve "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined" error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not quite what you were asking for, but probably as close to 'native' as you can get (a slightly more compact version of split/reduce snippet you provided):

```
var a = {b:{c:{d:5}}};
("b.c.d").split(".").reduce(function(p,c){return p && p[c];},a); //5
("b.c.e").split(".").reduce(function(p,c){return p && p[c];},a); //undefined
```

If you were hoping for a solution with a string like `"a.b.c.d"`, then you'll need to use `eval` (not recoomended) or the object `a` will need to be global (also not recommended) or the object will need to be a property of another object which is little self-defeating.

Answer (score -2):

I think I have another solution to this problem, I was trying to achieve this for minutes. If you are working on window scope you can use my function to see if the object exist or return a default value.

```
function parseObj(obj){
    try{
        return eval(obj);
    }catch(e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
alert(parseObj("a.b.c.d"));
```

---

I don't know if this is what you looking for but I am sure it will give you an another idea. Have a nice work.